# How to create promt in powershell to ask user on which server group run script

Tags: powershell, variables, select, remote-server

Good day, I have such set of servers

```
$libraryserver = ('192.168.0.3','192.168.0.4')
$dormetoryserver = ('192.168.1.15','192.168.1.16')
$teacherserver = ('192.168.1.110','192.168.1.112')
```

When user runs powershell script there should be prompt or arg - like: runscript.ps1 -library and after that $servers will be taken from libraryserver list

```
foreach($server in $servers) {
  # Destination UNC path changes based on server name
  $destinationPath = "\\$server\D$\tmp\"
  # Check that full folder structure exists and create if it doesn't
  if(!(Test-Path $destinationPath)) {
    # -Force will create any intermediate folders
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $destinationPath
  }
  # Copy the file across
  Copy-Item $sourcefile $destinationPath
}
```

Could you please help me ? thanks, tried to search and failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a parameter that only accepts one of three valid values (you can use the `ValidateSet` attribute for this), then pick the appropriate group based on the argument:

```
param(
  [ValidateSet('Library', 'Dormitory', 'TeachersLounge')]
  [string]$ServerGroup
)

$servers = @{
  Library        = '192.168.0.3','192.168.0.4'
  Dormitory      = '192.168.1.15','192.168.1.16'
  TeachersLounge = '192.168.1.110','192.168.1.112'
}[$ServerGroup]

foreach($server in $servers){
  # ...
}
```